# AngularJS: How to prevent/delay application of filters to avoid rearrangement of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've written a directive for a simple sider input.

The fiddle is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/PQXyxfmTbpaQE1ZnkQkq

The problem occurs when you change someone's age enough to change the order. Is there a way to hijack the ng-repeat element's parent scope to not apply filters?

Specifically, can I stop the elements from rearranging while the sliders are being dragged? Like, I would set some flag on the `mousedown` event which will stop the filtering, and remove that flag on the `mouseup` event to allow rearranging.

I've looked at the Angular source, and I'm pretty sure this can't be done at the moment, however I also welcome a modification of Angular that might allow this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own custom filter, and use it instead of `orderBy` in your view.  (However, your custom filter can inject `orderByFilter` and use it -- see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14223178/215945) for more info on that.)

```
<li ng-repeat="person in persons | myOrderBy:orderProp:doNotFilter">
```

Inside your custom filter, check argument `doNotFilter`, which is a scope property that your directive will set when you mousedown, and clear when you mouseup.  If the property is set, don't filter.

You'll have to pass the name of the "don't filter" property to your directives:

```
<slider min="0" max="100" step="1" ng-model="person.age" do-not-filter="doNotFilter">
```

An alternative would be to specify one or two controller methods for your directive to call on mousedown and mouseup.  Those methods would then affect the `doNotFilter` scope property.

```
<slider min="0" max="100" step="1" ng-model="person.age" 
    filter-stuff="filterStuff(filterState)">
```

Comment: Hi, I'm accepting your answer since there seems to be no alternative now, but I was intending this to be used as a standalone plugin.